# Can't install apps anymore - only via adb

Tags: applications, installation, adoptable-storage

I recently tried to extend my internal memory of my Moto G5 with a 128 gb sd card, so I backed up the previous smaller card to my pc, switched cards, formatted the new card as internal, copied back all the files and thought I was done. I wasn't.

I noticed that all the apps that I had parked on the sd card were not installed anymore, so I thought I'd install them again. When I tried to do that, the usual installation dialog opened but ended with "App was not installed". The
is happens whether I use Googley Play, Amazon App Store, or a local apk. With F-Droid it's a little different: It shows me that the installation failed because of an unknown error.

The only thing that seems to work is installing via adb, but that is rather impractical on the long run.

The phone is a Moto G5 running vanilla Android 8.1, and has about 1.5GB of free space in the internal storage. I tried the usual: empty cache and delete data of Google Play Store and Services, and rebooted several times before and after that.

Any ideas what I could do next?

Comment: You could try to fix this by uninstalling and re-installing the affected apps via adb: `adb uninstall -k <packagename>` will uninstall the app but keep it's data. This allows you to re-install the app without loosing the app-date.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Uninstalling this way works. Re-installing does not.